# JTextPane line wrap behavior

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtextpane, word-wrap

Recently I have been working on a Java text editor project and I would like to use a `JTextPane` to replace the old `JTextArea` in order to implement syntax highlighting. However, a `JTextPane` lacks methods in `JTextArea` (such as `append()`, `getLineStartOffset()` etc) and I want to reimplement them in my class `MyTextPane` (a sub-class of `JTextPane`) but have run into troubles.

My current code (only a small self-contained part):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class MyTextPane extends JTextPane
{
    public MyTextPane()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void append(String text)
    {
        try
        {
            Document doc = this.getDocument();
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),text,null);
        }
        catch (BadLocationException ex)
        {
            //must succeed
            throw new InternalError(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void insert(String text, int pos)
    {
        try
        {
            this.getStyledDocument().insertString(pos,text,null);
        }
        catch (BadLocationException ex)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void replaceRange(String str, int start, int end)
    {
        try
        {
            Document doc = this.getDocument();
            doc.remove(start,end-start);
            doc.insertString(start,str,null);
        }
        catch (BadLocationException ex)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void setLineWrap(boolean isLineWrap)
    {
        /*
         * implements later
         */
    }

    public boolean getLineWrap()
    {
        /*
         * implements later
         */
         return true;
    }

    public void setWrapStyleWord(boolean isWrapStyleWord)
    {
        /*
         * implements later
         */
    }

    public boolean getWrapStyleWord()
    {
        /*
         * implements later
         */
        return true;
    }

    public void setTabSize(int size)
    {
        /*
         * implements later
         */        
    }

    public int getTabSize()
    {
        /*
         * implements later
         */
        return 4;
    }

    public int getLineCount()
    {
        //follow JTextArea implementation
        Element root = this.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
        return root.getElementCount();
    }

    public int getLineStartOffset(int line) throws BadLocationException
    {
        //follow JTextArea implementation
        int count = this.getLineCount();
        Document doc = this.getDocument();
        if (line < 0)
        {
            throw new BadLocationException("Negative line", -1);
        }
        if (line >= count)
        {
            throw new BadLocationException("No such line", doc.getLength() + 1);
        }
        return doc.getDefaultRootElement().getElement(line).getStartOffset();
    }

    public int getLineEndOffset(int line) throws BadLocationException
    {
        //follow JTextArea implementation
        int count = this.getLineCount();
        Document doc = this.getDocument();
        if (line < 0)
        {
            throw new BadLocationException("Negative line", -1);
        }
        if (line >= count)
        {
            throw new BadLocationException("No such line", doc.getLength() + 1);
        }
        int end = doc.getDefaultRootElement().getElement(line).getEndOffset();
        return (line==count-1)?(end-1):end;
    }

    public int getLineOfOffset(int off) throws BadLocationException
    {
        //follow JTextArea implementation
        Document doc = this.getDocument();
        if (off < 0)
        {
            throw new BadLocationException("Can't translate offset to line", -1);
        }
        if (off > doc.getLength())
        {
            throw new BadLocationException("Can't translate offset to line", doc.getLength() + 1);
        }
        return doc.getDefaultRootElement().getElementIndex(off);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final SimpleAttributeSet BOLD_SET = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setBold(BOLD_SET, true);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(BOLD_SET, new Color(0,0,125));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {            
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                MyTextPane textPane = new MyTextPane();
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(textPane), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(200,200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have already added back some methods like `append()`. However, I can't think of any ways to control the line wrap policy.

The default behavior is quite strange: when there are one short word and one long word,

[image]

if I consecutively enter characters without a space,

[image]

it firstly appears like wrapping by words. However when I continue to enter characters,

[image]

it does not wrap at all.

Is there any elegant way to control the wrapping policy of a `JTextPane`? In other words, can a `JTextPane` wrap words like a `JTextArea`? I found so many duplicates (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702891/toggling-text-wrap-in-a-jtextpane), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156038/jtextpane-line-wrapping) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636186/jtextpane-wont-wrap)) but couldn't find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a discussion about the same problem: [Word wrapping behavior in JTextPane since Java 7](https://community.oracle.com/message/10692405). The solution proposed by user [StanislavL](https://community.oracle.com/people/StanislavL?customTheme=otn) (who also appears to be very active on Stack Overflow: [StanislavL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301607/stanislavl)) to support word wrapping works for me using Java 8. It uses a custom `WrapEditorKit` as the editor kit for the `JTextPane` (and the `WrapEditorKit` class in turn uses the `WrapColumnFactory` and `WrapLabelView` classes).

Combining this with the [NonWrappingTextPane example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/NonWrappingWrapTextPane.htm) (from the book Core Swing: Advanced Programming by Kim Topley) makes it possible to switch line wrapping off:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WrapTestApp extends JFrame {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        new WrapTestApp();
    }

    public WrapTestApp() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(800, 400, 200, 200);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final CustomTextPane textPane = new CustomTextPane(true);
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textPane.setText("ExampleOfTheWrapLongWordWithoutSpaces");
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The `CustomTextPane` class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class CustomTextPane extends JTextPane {
    private boolean lineWrap;

    public CustomTextPane(final boolean lineWrap) {
        this.lineWrap = lineWrap;

        if (lineWrap)
            setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        if (lineWrap)
            return super.getScrollableTracksViewportWidth();
        else
            return getParent() == null
                  || getUI().getPreferredSize(this).width <= getParent().getSize().width;
    }

    private class WrapEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit {
        private final ViewFactory defaultFactory = new WrapColumnFactory();

        @Override
        public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
            return defaultFactory;
        }
    }

    private class WrapColumnFactory implements ViewFactory {
        @Override
        public View create(final Element element) {
            final String kind = element.getName();
            if (kind != null) {
                switch (kind) {
                    case AbstractDocument.ContentElementName:
                        return new WrapLabelView(element);
                    case AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName:
                        return new ParagraphView(element);
                    case AbstractDocument.SectionElementName:
                        return new BoxView(element, View.Y_AXIS);
                    case StyleConstants.ComponentElementName:
                        return new ComponentView(element);
                    case StyleConstants.IconElementName:
                        return new IconView(element);
                }
            }

            // Default to text display.
            return new LabelView(element);
        }
    }

    private class WrapLabelView extends LabelView {
        public WrapLabelView(final Element element) {
            super(element);
        }

        @Override
        public float getMinimumSpan(final int axis) {
            switch (axis) {
                case View.X_AXIS:
                    return 0;
                case View.Y_AXIS:
                    return super.getMinimumSpan(axis);
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid axis: " + axis);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's fine but I still can't `setLineWrap(false)`

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. By the way I am using `SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(this);` instead because I am using a `JLayer` to wrap the `JTextPane`. =) Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to find a solution to this problem and since I didn't find it on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), I'm posting a [link to the solution](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2376090/word-wraping-behaviour-in-jtextpane-since-java-7).

In case this website ever ceases to exist, here is copy the code that is there:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WrapTestApp extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WrapTestApp();
    }

    public WrapTestApp() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200, 200);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
        jtp.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jtp);
        jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        getContentPane().add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jtp.setText("ExampleOfTheWrapLongWordWithoutSpaces");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class WrapEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit {

        ViewFactory defaultFactory = new WrapColumnFactory();

        public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
            return defaultFactory;
        }

    }

    class WrapColumnFactory implements ViewFactory {

        public View create(Element elem) {
            String kind = elem.getName();
            if (kind != null) {
                if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {
                    return new WrapLabelView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                    return new ParagraphView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)) {
                    return new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)) {
                    return new ComponentView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)) {
                    return new IconView(elem);
                }
            }

            // default to text display
            return new LabelView(elem);
        }
    }

    class WrapLabelView extends LabelView {

        public WrapLabelView(Element elem) {
            super(elem);
        }

        public float getMinimumSpan(int axis) {
            switch (axis) {
                case View.X_AXIS:
                    return 0;
                case View.Y_AXIS:
                    return super.getMinimumSpan(axis);
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid axis: " + axis);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All credits go to [StanislavL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301607/stanislavl).